# Python print statements being buffered with > output redirection

Tags: python, linux

I'm doing print statements in python. I'm executing my script like so:

```
python script.py > out.log nohup &
```

The print statements are not all showing up in `out.log` but the program is finishing ok.

That line of code is in an `.sh` file
I execute by doing `./script.sh`

**Update:** The log does get all the data but not until a certain # of lines are printed. It would appear to be buffering the output.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

When stdout is sent to a tty it will be line buffered and will be flushed every line, but when redirected to a file or pipe it'll be fully buffered and will only be flushed periodically when you overrun the buffer.

You'll have to add `sys.stdout.flush()` calls after each line if you want the output to be immediately visible, or disable buffering entirely. See [Disable output buffering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/107705/python-output-buffering) for ways to do the latter:

> 1. Use the `-u` command line switch
> 2. Wrap `sys.stdout` in an object that flushes after every write
> 3. Set `PYTHONUNBUFFERED` env var
> 4. `sys.stdout = os.fdopen(sys.stdout.fileno(), 'w', 0)`

Answer (score 1):

Did you try:

1. Running it without the redirection and making sure everything is printed as expected
2. Running it not through a shell script, but simply from a command line

?

These steps may help you "home in" on the problem.